# PHP - Foreach de auto ajuste

Tags: php, ponteiro, foreach

Durante o desenvolvimento, são muitas as vezes em que se realiza um requisição para o banco, na qual os dados retornados vem em array, algumas vezes é necessário realizar um `foreach` para ajustar estes dados ou ate mesmo incluir mais dados de acordo com um dado especifico.

#### Exemplo :

```
$dadosUsuario = $this->UsuarioModel->getDados('all');

foreach($dadosUsuario as $k => $dadoUsuario){

    $nome = $dadoUsuario['name'];
    $lastName = $dadoUsuario['name'];

    $fullName = sprintf('%s %s', $name, $lastName);

    $dadoUsuario['fullName'] = $fullName;

    $dadosUsuario[$k] = $dadoUsuario;
}
```

Note que foi necessário reatribuir o valor de `$dadosUsuario[$k]`

Teria algum mode de deixar isto mais dinâmico?

Comment: Você pode usar métodos como `array_walk()`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk.php ou `array_walk_recursive()` :  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sim teria**, a passagem por referencia **`&`**

#### Exemplo :

```
foreach($dadosUsuario as $k => &$dadoUsuario){

    $nome = $dadoUsuario['name'];
    $lastName = $dadoUsuario['name'];

    $fullName = sprintf('%s %s', $name, $lastName);

    $dadoUsuario['fullName'] = $fullName;
}
```

Note, o **`&`** em `$dadoUsuario`, assim a variável aponta diretamente para o indice do array, ou seja ela representa diretamente um ajuste no próprio `$dadosUsuario[$k]`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer, mas aqui tem um exemplo:

```
$dadoUsuario = array('... vem os dados do banco');


function getDadosUsuario($item, $key)
{
  $parseNames = explode(' ',$item['nome']);
   $fullName = $item['nome'];
   $fistName = $parseNames[0];
   $lastName = $parseNames[1];
   unset($names[0]); 
   $lastNameComplete = implode(' ',$parseNames); 

    $dadoUsuario[$key] = array(
         'nome_completo'      => $fullName,
         'nome'               => $fistName,
         'sobrenome'          => $lastName 
         'sobrenome_completo' => $lastNameComplete
   );

}

array_walk_recursive($dadosUsuario, 'getDadosUsuario');
```

Comment: Desculpe @Ivan, não sei se você compreendei o intuito da pergunta, mas eu só queria demostrar que é possível a passagem por referencia no ultimo elemento do `foreach`. Ja quanto ao código, eu não compreendi porque você fez um `explode` e `implode` sendo que eu posso simplesmente pegar `$item['nome']`. Mas Obrigado por participar.